# Resource Sizing with only static memory use

Tags: gcc, resources, arm, embedded, stm32

For my  embedded application, we are using a STM32F411 chip. The chip has 512kb of flash and 128kb of RAM. 
I wanted to do a resource sizing exersize so I can monitor how I am doing on resources (FLASH and RAM)

I only statically allocate memory with no Malloc() calls. and sizing with gcc gives me:

```
text      data     bss     dec    hex     filename
230868   11236   74048  316152   4d2f8   application.elf
```

From the readings I have done (https://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/04/14/text-data-and-bss-code-and-data-size-explained/) I understand that because there are no dynamically allocated resources, the above information should give me a clear measure of how deep into the RAM usage I will run.

Can I expect the RAM use to ultimately be the data section + the bss sections per the summary on the link above? So in this case 85284 bytes.

And the Flash size to be text + data sections. In this case: 242104 ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I expect the RAM use to ultimately be the data section + the bss
>   sections per the summary on the link above? So in this case 85284
>   bytes.

Depending on your linker script. Especially stack and heap configuration. Same is with the text segment & data segment.

For more detailed information you need to see the .map file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but also consider that even though you don't explicitly use dynamic memory in your code, library functions might. If you're trying to maintain super-tight control over memory use and you have an application that uses close to your total amount of RAM, you'll need to account for that. If you don't, you may run into nasty runtime issues.

Answer (score -1):

In short, yes. Because of the need to store the initializers for the initialized data section, the "data" section counts twice in the memory usage -- once for flash and once for RAM. This is also why it is important to be very diligent about declaring constant data as "const". That data is then placed in flash and only counts once in the overall memory usage.

Comment: His code runs without a stack?  I think he needs to account for that.  Sometimes devices need memory outside of `bss` as well.  It would be best to use a custom linker file to have it check for exceeding the hardware sizes.  You vector tables might need to be in special location and requires some space as well.

Comment: As PeterJ's answer indicates, if you want to count down to the last byte, you need a linker map to account for stack, heap and anything else. The default linker scripts provided by most vendors are quite adequate. And, yes, the size program does not tell everything. Judgement and experience are still required.

Comment: 411 is the easy one. It has only one block of RAM. But even £2 STM32F3 have a CCMRAM which is not taken into the account. I use it for the variables & data which are accessed by DMA + stack & heap and sometimes for the time sensitive routines,  and "normal" SRAM for everything else. of course custom linker script and startup routines are required